# Github https push error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192B | 300.24 MiB/s with LFS enabled

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

So, I have a game project which is a little over 11gb in size. Since some files are above 100mb, I am using git lfs.
I have never run into this error, I am also not extremely proficient with GitHub so this might just be a newbie error. Whenever I try to push this project to my git repo it throws this error-

```
git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 14707, done.
Counting objects: 100% (14707/14707), done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10071/10071), done.
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192B | 300.24 MiB/s
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
error: failed to push some refs to <project>
```

I have been trying to fix this for a while now and am unsure of what to do now. I use the https link of the repo to push and I'm using windows. It's a new repo with no previous commits so I'm really confused on what I should do now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default, or any sort of proxy or TLS MITM device?  Are you using HTTPS or SSH?  What version of Git and Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any antivirus and am using https. Windows version- 10.0.19044. Git version 2.37.1.windows.1